# How to I represent a '<' character in my XML documentation?

Tags: c++, special-characters, xml-documentation

I've seen various questions here on SO involving [Microsoft's XML documentation tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx), but I'm having trouble adding some example code:

```
/// <summary>Return the oldest acceptable timestamp for a data packet.</summary>
/// <example>
/// if( GetOldestValidResultTime() < lastResultTime )
/// {
///     Console::WriteLine("Results are too old");
/// }
/// </example>
/// <returns>The timestamp (the Milliseconds field from a raw result) of the oldest acceptable data item given the timestamp in the latest result in the internal buffer.</returns>
long GetOldestValidResultTime();
```

This gives me:

```
DataProcessor.h(154) : warning C4635: XML document comment applied to 'MyApp.DataProcessor.GetOldestValidResultTime': badly-formed XML: Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.
```

Is there any way around this other than using `&lt;` which makes examples much harder to follow if you're reading the source directly as opposed to DOxygen output (for example)? ..or is the `&lt;` code the only option here?

**[Edit]** I've tried the suggested CDATA block but it only appears to work for single-lines:

```
/// <example><![CDATA[ test < 5; ]]></example>
/// <example>
/// <![CDATA[ test < 5; ]]>
/// </example>
```

..but not multi-line comments which might actually make for a readable example:

```
/// <example><![CDATA[ 
/// test < 5;
/// ]]> </example>
```

**[Edit2]** Tried pierrre's suggestion of removing the \\'s from in front of the last two statements which predictably failed:

```
/// <example><![CDATA[ 
test < 5;
]]> </example>
```

gives:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

Comment: One of many reasons why XML is the wrong format for documentation markup. :-) (A similar problem exists in Javadoc as well, don't get me wrong, but it's slightly less intrusive because HTML is more forgiving than XML.) And I *think* the answer is "no, you have to use &lt;", but I'm not expert in this area so don't take my word for it (hence not *answering*).

Answer (score 4):

Use a CDATA block.

Comment: Tried this, but it only appears to work for a single line? See the edit I just made.

Comment: In a CDATA block you can add lot of things and is not single lined. Try to remove /// in front of test <5 and /// in front of ]]>

Comment: Look at this: http://www.shrinkrays.net/code-snippets/csharp/-net-xml-comment-cheat-sheet.aspx. Removing the /// is not necessary

Comment: I just tried their sample and it doesn't seem to work for me.